# VS 2008 VB snippets for C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, code-snippets

I recently made the switch to a new job and consequently the switch from VB.NET to C#.  One thing that I miss is all the snippets that are available in VB.NET.  VB.NET comes with ~400 snippets and C# only comes with ~100.  Also, I have noticed that the majority of VB.NET snippets are task oriented which is exceptionally helpful when you hit those tasks that you only do every now and again (e.g. DeterminetheAmountofIsolatedStorageAvailable).

So, before I go through the pain of converting my favorite VB.NET snippets over to C#, does anyone know if someone has already done this and made it available for download?

I've searched for this for a few days now and haven't come up with anything.

Comment: Apparently this was a download at some point from Microsoft because Jeff posted about it.  Alas, the link is broken and Jeff's zip of the snippets no longer exists.
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000522.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the original C# Task-Based code snippets finally.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa718338.aspx

Now, can anyone tell why it needs to be an msi instead of just a plain old zip? *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

Having used QuickCode.NET (free) before Visual Studio added snippets, I've found that I still prefer to use QuickCode.NET. The QuickCode website has many user-created templates on their website.